# How to sign with gradle and gpg2

Tags: gradle, gnupg

The gradle signing plugin requires secring.gpg keyring file, according to the documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html

But since gpg version 2.1 the secring.gpg does not exist anymore. 
https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html

Is there a possibility to use the signing plugin of gradle with gpg >= 2.1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue and solved it by manually creating a secring.gpg file by executing the following terminal command:

```
gpg --keyring secring.gpg --export-secret-key XXXXXXXX > secring.gpg
```

You have to replace XXXXXXXX with the ID of the key you want to use. You can list all available keys by using the command `gpg --list-key`.

Edit: I forgot to mention, that I am using Linux.

Comment: In fact this does not work. The generated file is not a valid keyring and Gradle rejects it (Gralde 2.11).

Comment: Worked for me. But instead of piping the output to the file, I used GPG's -o option to let it write the file for me ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I also faced with the same issue that I could'n solve with the `gpg --export-secret-key`, like this.

> gpg: WARNING: nothing exported

Actually my gpg's version was 1.4.xx (with `gpg --version`) and there was another: **gpg2**.

So try this:

```
gpg2 --export-secret-key XXXXXXXX > secring.gpg
```

Comment: On Mac I had to use
gpg --export-secret-keys > ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg

Comment: i used `gpg --export-secret-key XXXXXXXX > secring.gpg` and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For people reaching this issue in 2017+, starting with Gradle 4.5, using GnuPG 2 (and gpg-agent) is fully supported. From the signing plugin [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:using_gpg_agent):

```
signing {
    useGpgCmd()
    sign configurations.archives
}
```

In addition, there have to be defined (at least) `signing.gnupg.keyName` (most likely in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`).

Please pay attention that the properties to defined key (`signing.gnupg.keyName`), key store (`signing.gnupg.homeDir`), passphrase (`signing.gnupg.passphrase`), etc. differ from those used in the previous Gradle versions (are in `signing.gnupg.*` not just `signing.*`).

Comment: If this is truly accurate, it would be very nice to get the Gradle documentation updated.  It still shows the older values - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:signatory_credentials

Comment: fwiw, I currently get the same failure regardless of which form I use - https://github.com/gradle-nexus/nexus-publish-e2e-minimal/issues/1